# Checking first item of array in Javascript Goes Wrong

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an empty array named `az` and when I `console.log(az)`, it returns this:

```
['']
```

Now I want to check that if `az` variable returns this `['']` value, go to first condition, otherwise goto 2nd condition:

```
if(az[0] == null){
    console.log(1);
}else{
    console.log(2);
}
```

So when I run the *if..else*, I get **2** meaning that `az[0]` is not set to *`null`*

So what's going wrong here?

How can I properly if the variable `az` is set to null array (`['']`) properly?

Comment: `['']` is NOT empty

Comment: Only `undefined` and `null` loosely equal(`==`) to `null`, try using `if(!az[0])` as the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `""` (empty string) instead of null.

example:

```
if(arr[0] == ""){
    console.log(1);
}else{
    console.log(2);
}
```

Comment: Though this answers the problem OP asked, BUT it's not an empty array check. it checks for a non-empty array if the first element is an empty string

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is, you want to print 1 if the list is empty, 2 if the list is not. For that you can do the following

```
if(az.length == 0)
{
   console.log(1);
}
else
{
   console.log(2);
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is how you check empty arrays

```
if(!az.length) {
   console.log("Empty array");
} else {
   console.log("Not an empty array");
}
```

Comment: Although Not Working

Comment: Why are you logging "empty array" in the second one as well?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @PaulGhiran sorry, I forgot to change the second log ^^